# Store infinite decimals C#

Tags: c#, math, decimal

I need to do some calculations with fractions which result have infinite decimals. 
For example:

```
240/360=0.666666...
```

The output has infinite decimals and when I multiply this by an integer the result must be an integer. So I've coded this way:

```
result = someInteger * decimal.divide(240/360);
```

(Try with someInteger = 2,700)
But the result has decimal values and some calculators or even spreadsheets would output an integer result.
How do I get same results in c#?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to round up / down or truncate? Try casting result to an int like so `var myIntResult = (int)result;`

Comment: Rounding or truncating won't let me if the operation returned an integer number, and that's what in fact i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The output has infinite decimals and when I multiply this by an integer the result must be an integer.

That won't really happen.

What you can do is careful rounding (after the multiplication).

Or instead of

```
 result = someInteger * decimal.divide(240/360);
```

you can use

```
 result = someInteger * 240 / 360;
```

what's the problem with that?

When you're really serious about working with fractions and *keeping* the precision you'll need a special type:

```
struct Rational 
{
  public readonly int Numerator;
  public readonly int Denominator;

  // lots of members, including operators
}
```

There are [libraries and examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RationalNumbers.aspx) for how to do this.

But note that you still won't be able to represent π exactly.

Comment: In your suggestion (result = someInteger * 240 / 360;) What operation has the higher priority? or which would be executed first?

Comment: Left to right... someInteger *240, then the answer to that / 360.

Comment: I note that of course you can represent pi exactly if you want to, *just not with a library of integer rationals*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no need to represent pi =)

Answer (score 1):

you could store the numerator and denominator separately as integers and multiply the numerator first before dividing, this wont fix every problem though as 1/3 * 2 will still give an infinite decimal. This also only works for rational numbers.

Comment: By doing the numerator first, you do open up the door to arithmetic overflows depending on the type; by dividing first, you're back to the infinite decimal problem.

Comment: yeah that is true quite a non trivial problem really

Comment: @AustinSalonen: While it is true you may end up with arithmetic overflows, that is easy enough to solve by doing your arithmetic in a larger bit space. By accepting `int` as input, and returning `int`, but using `long` internally, you should avoid the vast majority of problems.

Answer (score 0):

use `Math.Round()`

```
result = someInteger * decimal.divide(240/360);

result = Math.Round(result);
```

Returning a whole number is what you're asking to do right?

Comment: I don't want to round result, I just want to know if output is in fact an integer number

Comment: So you want the method to return a true/false statement if it's an integer? Because that's totally not what your question states.

Comment: yep, actually the code I'm working that does that comparison but my problem was with this operatin

Comment: @JorgeZapata then why don't you factor the numerator and denominator?

Answer (score 0):

Many applications perform pseudo fractional mathematics by doing intermediary calculations to a higher degree of accuracy than what will eventually be needed/output to the user (Office does this). If this isn't what you want, and you want to perform true fractional mathematics then search around for a Fractions implementation. There seems to be a decent implementation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/fractiion.aspx). The problem with such implementations is that the onus is on being functionally correct over being efficient. Thus, if your application needs to be performing millions of operations with fractions then its performance may suffer.